# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I am trying to make boxcox transformation of a variable (i.e. sqrt.CR) with lambda value from  -2 to 2. On running the below R code it gives a error of invalid atomic vectors. Later on checking earlier posts i saw few suggestions to transform the matrix into a data frame. Though the error continued to show up. Do anyone know to figure out this error ?

R code.

Matrix to data frame conversion

```
drivers.data<-as.data.frame(drivers)
```

Boxcox transfrom.

```
drivers$box_CR<-boxcox(drivers.data$sqrt.CR,lambda=seq(-2,2))
```

Comment: Please provide the sample data for reproducibility.

Comment: sqrt.CR
 0.62209324
 0.42308392
 0.34351128
 0.67970582
 0.27202941
 0.61806149
 0.46043458
 0.37416574
 0.36606010
 0.44045431
 0.39242834
 0.45055521
 0.31144823
 0.09486833
 0.67823300
 0.41472883
 0.52915026
 0.38858718
 0.33166248
 0.40620192

Answer (score 6):

The input to boxcox must be the output of a lm or aov call, not a vector of numbers as yours appears to be. See `?boxcox`.

> boxcox(object, ...)
>   Arguments:
>   object: a formula or fitted model object.  Currently only ‘lm’ and
>             ‘aov’ objects are handled.

Answer (score 4):

It could be because of package conflict, in MASS,boxcox requires a model object lm, whereas in bestNormalize it requires a vector.

Try

```
bestNormalize::boxcox(drivers.data)
```